# react Form.Control model/value mapping

Tags: reactjs

just starting to use React and trying to create a simple page with an input and a button.

```
class Register extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.user = {};
  }
  register(user){
    console.log(user);
  }
  render() {
    return (
    ........
    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Email address" value={this.user.email}/>
    ........
    <Button onClick={ () => this.register(this.user)}> Sign Up </Button>
    )
  }
}
```

I keep getting undefined when i tried to access {this.user.email}.
I'm coming from using Angular, so I've been used to using ng-model. What's the correct way to map the value so i can access it in the method 'register'?

Comment: I believe you would have wanted to set it as part of the component's state?

Comment: you need to do [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in your email field event handler to set the user email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input elements should be [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), they maintain their own state and that state is updated based on user input

```
class Register extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       email: '',
       password: ''
    };
  }

  onChangeHandler = (event) => {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    ........
    <Form.Control 
        type="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Email address"
        value={this.state.email}
        onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
    />
    <Form.Control 
        type="password"
        name="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={this.state.password}
        onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
    />
    ........
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: then how would i handle is there are multiple values/Form.Control?

Comment: @HangLin i have updated my answer to show you how you can have multiple input fields in react and update their values based on user input

Answer (score 0):

Try using State:

```
const React = require('react');
const {render} = require('react-dom');

class Register extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { user: {} };
  }
  register(user){
    console.log(user);
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Email address" value={this.state.user.email}/>
    <Button onClick={ () => this.register(this.state.user)}> Sign Up </Button>
    )
  }
}


render(Register, document.getElementById('root'))
```